# How to change the key of an object to match the parameter passed into the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When the following function runs the parameter 'state' will be an abbreviation for one of the US 50 states. I want the state key in the return block to not be read as 'state', but instead, one of the 50 us state variables passed into the function. What can I do?

```
  config = (state) => {
      return {
        state: {
          fill: 'gray'
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use square parens to use the value of a variable as a key name:

```
config = (state) => {
  return {
    [state]: {
      fill: 'gray'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answered my question, so thank you, but it did not solve the problem I'm having on my website.

Comment: @SalvatoreDePalma you should still accept an answer, though.   We can't answer a question about a problem that you never asked about.

Comment: @SalvatoreDePalma You should accept the answer if it solves the question you asked

Answer (score 1):

```
config = state => ({
   [state]: {
      fill: 'gray',
   }
})
```

Javascript allows you to do this with dynamic key name.

**How to be clean with ES6**:

you can also omit the `return` keyword if you're not doing anything else in the function other than returning an object.

You can also omit the parens around the params if `state` is the only param you need.

This solution is as clean as it gets

Comment: some coders prefer to use the parens even for single parameter functions.

Comment: @Alnitak True, it's all preference